# Categories calling in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, label

I have started learning swift recently and doing categories in swift 3 now.I have added a extension in Viewcontroller A and added a function to strikethrough label.text in a object class,CustomText.Now,everythiing is done the only thing I ma missing is the call to that new extension method.
Below is the code:

```
  ViewControllerA

extension String {
    func setLabelText(){
    let cell = ProductListingCell()
    let text = CustomText()
     cell.discountLabel.attributedText = text.getTextToStrikeThrough(label:cell.discountLabel)
    }
```

CustomText

```
func getTextToStrikeThrough(label:UILabel) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:label.text!)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    label.attributedText = attributeString
    let str  = label.attributedText
    return str!
}
```

Kindly help me to understand that how this extension String should be bring in function ,so that debugger goes on it and does the desired task.Thanks in advance!

Comment: That won’t really work for you; you are just creating a new instance of a cell and setting some text on it. That cell isn’t displayed anywhere and it will be thrown away as soon as the function exits. If you do want to do this as an extension then it should be an extension on `UILabel` and then you would say something like `someLabel.setStrikethroughText(myString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand what extensions do, they extend a base class, like @Paulw11 mentioned you could add an extension to UILabel like so

```
extension UILabel {
    func strikeThrough() {
        let attribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle : 2]

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self.text!, attributes: attribute);

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Then you when you have a `UILabel` you can just do

```
label.strikeThrough()
```

Or you could also extend String like:

```
extension String {
    func strikeThroughAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle : 2]

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: attribute);

        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Which you could use like so:

```
label.attributedText = label.text!.strikeThroughAttributedString()
```

I hope this will be a good example of how extensions can be used

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions regarding the code and I will gladly respond